# MinMaxAI checkers implementation

Tags: java

I can't seem to get my min max AI to work. This is the code so far. I get an error saying my allScores array is empty so it won't set my move to the bestScored move. Any help would be appreciated.

```
int[] move;

public static int makeMove(Board board, int currentPlayerColor, int maxingPlayerColor){

    int score = 0;
    int[] moveIndex={};

    if (Rules.gameOver(board)[0]==1){

        if(Rules.gameOver(board)[1] == maxingPlayerColor){
            System.out.println("1");
            return score = 1;
        } else if(Rules.gameOver(board)[1] == Math.abs(maxingPlayerColor-1)) {
            System.out.println("-1");
            return score = -1;
        } else{
            System.out.println("0");
            return score = 0;
        }

    } else {

        int[][] availableMoves = board.availableMoves(board, currentPlayerColor);
        int[] allScores = {};

        System.out.println("loop length: "+ availableMoves.length);

        for(int x = 0; x<availableMoves.length; x++){
            Board temp = board;

            if(currentPlayerColor == maxingPlayerColor){
                Board.doMove(availableMoves[x], temp, 7);
            } else {
                Board.doMove(availableMoves[x], temp, 0);
            }

            System.out.println(""+x);

            allScores = add(makeMove(temp,Math.abs(maxingPlayerColor-1), maxingPlayerColor), allScores);

            System.out.println("allscore len "+ allScores.length);

        }

        if(currentPlayerColor == maxingPlayerColor){

            for(int x = 0; x<allScores.length; x++){
                if(score < allScores[x]){
                    allScores = add(score, allScores);
                }
            }

            for(int x = 0; x<allScores.length; x++){
                if(score == allScores[x]){
                    moveIndex = add(x,moveIndex);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("max "+moveIndex.length);
            move = availableMoves[rand.nextInt(moveIndex.length)];

        } else {

            for(int x = 0; x<allScores.length; x++){
                if(score > allScores[x]){
                    score = allScores[x];
                }
            }

            for(int x = 0; x<allScores.length; x++){
                if(score == allScores[x]){
                    moveIndex = add(x,moveIndex);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("min "+moveIndex.length);
            move = availableMoves[rand.nextInt(moveIndex.length)];

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little more what you're trying to achieve? And why it isn't working?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! You've definitely come to the right place to get high quality help with your coding issues. This high quality standard carries over to questions as well, and you will find the more effort you put into making your question, the more effort other users put into answers your question. You can refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure your questions are high quality! Always remember to include a description of what your code attempts to accomplish, any error messages, and examples of your input and output. And again, welcome!

Comment: There are so many issues that I think the best thing to do would be to go back to basics and review Java syntax and do some very basic problems before you come back to this program.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add elements onto an array with

```
allScores = add(...
```

But that isn't how it works. You can't actually add elements onto an array, you can only change existing elements.

So when you make the array, you have this:

```
int[] allScores = {};
```

But that creates an empty array and you can't do anything with that. Instead, declare it like this:

```
int[] allScores = new int[SIZE];
```

Replacing `SIZE` with the number of elements you want the array to hold.

Then you can access and change certain elements like this:

```
allScores[index] = someNumber;
```

There are also some formatting and syntax errors. Try using a text editor or IDE that includes syntax highlighting to find easy mistakes.

Also read over [this guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm) to learn about arrays.

Comment: add is a seperate function I made to add an element to an array. Add is not my where my problem lies.

Comment: @Quinn It doesn't matter what the function is, you can not add elements to an array. You could make a new array that's one size larger than the previous and copy over all of the old array elements and place the new element at the end. But that's incredible inefficient and there are better ways to do what you want to do. Look up ArrayLists and when posting questions here, make sure you aren't falling victim to the XY problem.